# To see All the content (not just objects) in a package in R

Tags: r

This is likely a newbie's question but I think I did my homework and yet have not found the answer (I hope to find) so I am posting it here to seek some assistance.

Similar questions were asked before but from what I found, no answer could help me with the current issue except an "expensive" solution, which requires an editor for R.

I learned that `ls` and `objects` allow us to view the objects inside a package. But even with `ls(all.names=TRUE)`, I still couldn't see **all** the content. Someone suggested `ls(getNAMEspace)` but still this isn't "good" enough for me.

e.g.

```
>search()
[1]".GlobalEvn"      "package:TCGAGBM"
>ls("package:TCGAGBM")
character(0)
>ls(getNamespace("TCGAGBM"),all.names=TRUE)
[1]"._NAMESPACE_."   "._S3MethodsTable_."  ".packageName"
```

However, under C (cmd), I see the following

> C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\R\R-2.15.1\library\TCGAGBM
>    .   ..  data  extdata ...... (total 3 File(s), 7 Dir(s))

I came across this "discrepancy" when I saw the following line of script -

```
>clinical=read.delim(system.file(
+"extdata/Clinical/clinical_patient_public_GBM.txt.gz",
+package="TCGAGBM"), header=TRUE)
```

Thus I was wondering if there is a way under R to see ALL the content within a package so that we could "know" how better to utilize the package. Vignette would probably help, but in my limited experience with R so far, I have found that some packages did not come with Vignette.

Any comment will be appreciated to help me learn more about R.

Comment: Do you want to see all the source code files etc? If you want to see contents of the package directory, try something like `list.files(system.file(package = 'TCGAGBM'), recursive = T, full.names = T))` - but this will be OS dependent as to how much you actually see due to the way `R` packages are packaged for windows / linux etc

Comment: maybe `data(package='TCGAGBM')`

Comment: According to googling `TCGAGBM r package`, there seems to be a tutorial for this package at http://watson.nci.nih.gov/~sdavis/tutorials/TCGA_data_integration/ . Perhaps better to start by following that?  Digging into the internals of a package is a last resort ...

Comment: @mnel, post comment as answer?

Comment: great answer `ls(getNamespace("TCGAGBM"),all.names=TRUE)` 

Answer (score 5):

My preferred approach *by far* is to simply look at *the source code* of a package in question.

In fact, I actually do that pretty often as running [CRANberries](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/cranberries) creates a local CRAN mirror as a side effect.  But even if you don't, CRAN packages really are only a quick download away and will come *with comments* in the source which the parsed code excludes.

*Edit*: I just found what Ben found too: Sean Davis' page at http://watson.nci.nih.gov/~sdavis/tutorials/TCGA_data_integration/ -- looks like it uses some BioC packages too.  I would still study the source which often has more comments, annotations, extras, ... than the installed package.  But maybe that's just my preference. YMMV as they say.

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys. To mnel, I think for now list.files will do the job. To Ben, I read the tutorial but was thinking (while reading it) what if I didn't have the tutorial, how would I know there is an "extdata" to extract more info? Thanks A LOT for all helpful info as I am just a 3 month R baby still finding my way.

Comment: @BChen: My pleasure, and welcome to StackOverflow. It is customary to upvote a good answer (which you may or may not have done) and to accept one if it is seen as helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another way to explore the functionality of any package. Although it is not as comprehensive a solution as Dirk's, it is still useful. When I want to know all the functionality of a package, I quickly list all of its functions. Then if I'm curious about any function, I an quickly pull up the help file `?function_name` and see what it does. For that reason, I keep this function in my `.rprofile` so it automatically loads every time I run `R`.

```
lsp <- function (package, all.names = FALSE, pattern) {
    package <- deparse(substitute(package))
    ls(pos = paste("package", package, sep = ":"), all.names = all.names, 
        pattern = pattern)
}
```

This is especially helpful when I know the partial name of a function and what package it belongs to but quickly need to find it.

e.g.

```
> lsp(ggplot2, pattern = "geom")
 [1] "geom_abline"          "geom_area"           
 [3] "geom_bar"             "geom_bin2d"          
 [5] "geom_blank"           "geom_boxplot"        
 [7] "geom_contour"         "geom_crossbar"       
 [9] "geom_density"         "geom_density2d"      
[11] "geom_dotplot"         "geom_errorbar"       
[13] "geom_errorbarh"       "geom_freqpoly"       
[15] "geom_hex"             "geom_histogram"      
[17] "geom_hline"           "geom_jitter"         
[19] "geom_line"            "geom_linerange"      
[21] "geom_map"             "geom_path"           
[23] "geom_point"           "geom_pointrange"     
[25] "geom_polygon"         "geom_quantile"       
[27] "geom_raster"          "geom_rect"           
[29] "geom_ribbon"          "geom_rug"            
[31] "geom_segment"         "geom_smooth"         
[33] "geom_step"            "geom_text"           
[35] "geom_tile"            "geom_violin"         
[37] "geom_vline"           "update_geom_defaults"
```

Comment: That's nice. I had been using TAB in ESS which gives about the same, but this filters the internal names away.  Obnoxious note: You do have the opening brace in the wrong spot though :)  R Core style all the way.

Comment: Is it just too hard to remember this syntax `ls('package:ggplot2', pattern='geom')`?  If you're going to look at help pages for functions next anyway, maybe `help(package='ggplot2', help_type='html')` is more appropriate.

Comment: It's a great idea. The only minor quirk is that the package to be listed needs to have been previously imported using `library()`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to see all the system files for a particular package, then try something like

```
list.files(system.file(package = 'TCGAGBM'), recursive = T, full.names = T)
```

How useful this will be will depend on your OS, as the way packages are installed is OS dependent

see the appropriate section in [R Installation and Administration manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Windows-packages) for more details.

## NOTE

@DirkEddelbuettel's suggestion of inspecting the source is a *far* better approach.

Comment: will follow up on this, but as of now, the baby cannot know how to use a "dictionary" yet