# How to see all methods, objects, dataframse, etc of a package in R?

Tags: r, object

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575098/to-see-all-the-content-not-just-objects-in-a-package-in-r) and in fact, is answered there. But because it took me a lot effort to find the answer there. I preferred to create a new more organized one and answer it myself.Now the question is:

**If I want to see all methods, dataframes, etc of a package that I only know its name, what should I do to access them very easily?**

Answer (score 0):

Just enter this code:

```
help(package='PACKAGENAME', help_type='html')
```

for example to see all you have in the R basic package, **stats**:

```
help(package='stats',help_type='html')
```

Comment: Note that specifying the help_type isn't necessary to answer the question and is entirely a matter of preference.

Comment: This only shows you things that are documented